# Silverlight how do I add a "select all" option to a checkbox list?

Tags: silverlight

I have a checkbox list in Silverlight.  It's actually a Telerik rad combo box with checkboxes in it.

What I'm trying to do is add an initial item to that list with the label "Select All".  When the user clicks on that item it will select or deselect the items in the list.  In addition, when the user deselects on of the items it should deselect the "Select All".

The problem is that I have a CheckedItemsChanged event that fires when an item in the list is changed.  If I try to change the list during that event it complains that I can't change a collection while in the collection changed event.

Is there another way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're attempting to do something like

```
void SomeComboBox_CheckedItemsChanged(object sender, SomeEventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff with checked items in list
}
```

Does it help if you use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to do the stuff involving the checked items, i.e. something like the following?

```
void SomeComboBox_CheckedItemsChanged(object sender, SomeEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        // Do stuff with checked items in list
    });
}
```